# White right margin on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I made a website which displays correctly on desktop but on mobile devices I get a large white margin on the right side of the screen. I tried every solution I found so far, meaning the following basically:

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Tried every combination but the most I could get out of it is that I didnt have the margin but instead a vertical scrolllbar which isnt too good either. Could please someone help me with my issue?

You can see this problem [here](http://tectumit.com).

Comment: Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1):

You should set also max-width: 100%;, or try to find element in your html code (using development tools in your browser) which has width property value higher than mobile screen resolution.

I found that the .menu2 class element have negative margin value. Setting this to 0, and changing width of .main element to 100% instead of value in ems solved this problem in my browser.